# Website not scaling correctly in Android web browser

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm developing a mobile website. It's working fine on iPhone in Safari using the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.5; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=1;" />
```

In Android, the website is scaling to about 480 pixels in width and only taking up about half of the web browser, meaning the left side has the website at approximately 480 pixels in width and the right side is blank.

If I change the meta tag to this, it works fine:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=680; initial-scale=0.5; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=1;" />
```

So "hard coding" the width at 680 pixels works, however I don't want to do this as this website is designed to accommodate multiple sizes. I tried adding `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` to the meta tag with no luck. What else can I do to have my website scale to the device's width on Android?

Comment: You could try solve this with css: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/

Answer (score 1):

I 'solved' it by using `$('body').css({ width: $(document).width() })` in jQuery, since the site already relies on JavaScript. I realize this is not a clean solution, but it works and I'm tired, so for now it'll have to do. If anybody has a better solution I'd love to hear it.